# How to determine irreducibility over the algebraic numbers in Mathematica?

Tags: polynomials, algebra

How can the irreducibility over the algebraic numbers be determined in Mathematica for a given univariate or multivariate polynomial with algebraic coefficients?

In particular: How should the field of the algebraic numbers be specified therefore?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[x^5+2x+1]
```

which returns True and

```
Factor[x^5+2x+1]
```

returns the original polynomial while

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[x^5+x+1]
```

returns False and

```
Factor[x^5+x+1]
```

returns

```
(1+x+x^2)(1-x^2+x^3)
```

The documentation for `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IrreduciblePolynomialQ.html shows how you provide the field extension that you desire.

Comment: Did you read all the documentation for `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` including clicking on the orange Details and Options and reading the information included there? That tells you what it can do and what control you have over the process.

Comment: As the docs state, use `Extension->All`.

Comment: Assuming the input coefficients are in Q, all roots are in the algebraic closure of Q. If coefficients are not in Q then it becomes a different problem. Also one that I suspect is amenable to ordinary factorization followed by the irreducibility test applied only if there is a single factor with coefficients in Q.

Comment: Steps: (1) `Factor[poly]` (2) If there are multiple factors with coeffs in Q then it is reducible. (3) If there is a unique factor, call it `polyq`, with coeffs in Q, then do `IrreduciblePolynomialQ[polyq,Extension->All]`. Result is result of that computation. (4) Exercise for reader: why can we discard factors from step (1) that have coeffs not in Q? Also this all assumes there are no coeffs in `poly` that are algebraic numbers. If there are, this will need minor modifications.